# How to clean up orphaned resources to reduce storage capacity in Common Data Service (Microsoft Dataverse)?

Tags: powerapps

I've been trying to find a solution, but the closest I came across was this forum where script execution to free up orphan resources is mentioned.

[Database size in MB WebResourceBase](https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=1285&MessageKey=241a59dd-2af0-4bfa-a99c-c882e34547be&CommunityKey=dc83c23b-ede0-4070-ae7a-dd90859148a6&tab=digestviewer#bm241a59dd-2af0-4bfa-a99c-c882e34547be)

But I really don't know if there is another way to handle this situation. The main reason I'm looking for that is to get free space to create environments.
[Example of how it exceeds its capacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCsNu.png)
[Resources that take up space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx9bq.jpg)

Thank you very much for your help. Regards!

Comment: Reach out to MS support, they can give you script, tips to achieve what you want.